# Tkinter task bar icon error

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, tkinter, icons

I have recently upgraded python from version 3.6.3 to 3.6.4 . In doing so, `tkinter` has become corrupt with the windows task bar displaying a blank icon (please see the image below).

[image: Icon error example in IDLE]

I have done some `tkinter` troubleshooting and a simplified version is shown below with the two skipped tests (should this be of use).

```
test_actual (test_font.FontTest) ... ok
test_configure (test_font.FontTest) ... ok
test_eq (test_font.FontTest) ... ok
test_families (test_font.FontTest) ... ok

...

test_put (test_images.PhotoImageTest) ... ok
test_subsample (test_images.PhotoImageTest) ... ok
test_write (test_images.PhotoImageTest) ... ok
test_zoom (test_images.PhotoImageTest) ... ok
testLoadTk (test_loadtk.TkLoadTest) ... skipped 'No $DISPLAY set.'
testLoadTkFailure (test_loadtk.TkLoadTest) ... ok
test_generated_names (test_misc.MiscTest) ... ok
test_repr (test_misc.MiscTest) ... ok
test_tk_setPalette (test_misc.MiscTest) ... ok]

...

test_keys (test_widgets.ToplevelTest) ... ok
test_menu (test_widgets.ToplevelTest) ... ok
test_padx (test_widgets.ToplevelTest) ... ok
test_pady (test_widgets.ToplevelTest) ... ok
test_relief (test_widgets.ToplevelTest) ... ok
test_screen (test_widgets.ToplevelTest) ... skipped 'No $DISPLAY set.'
test_takefocus (test_widgets.ToplevelTest) ... ok
test_use (test_widgets.ToplevelTest) ... ok
test_visual (test_widgets.ToplevelTest) ... ok
test_width (test_widgets.ToplevelTest) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 728 tests in 8.087s

OK (skipped=2)
```

I know it is tkinter not IDLE as all my .pyw projects have the same problem. If any more details are needed please just let me know.

Comment: do you want to have a custom icon? or just the normal tkinter icon?

Comment: Either would be nice!

Comment: I can tell you how to do custom one

Comment: just do `root.iconbitmap(r"file.ico")` yes there is an r

Comment: Sorry, I think you miss understood. I can do that but ANY icon will not show on the taskbar.

Comment: oh, that is weird, try reinstalling python

Comment: or maybe just tkinter

Comment: I have tried repairing and modifying Python as well as restarting my computer but it is still happening :'(

Comment: does it work 3.6.3?

Comment: it is not important that you have **The latest** version of python, especially if it is broken

Comment: I installed 3.6.3 fresh and it worked perfectly (I haven't tried uninstalling Python then reinstalling it as 3.6.4 but this shouldn't make a difference right?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163594/discussion-between-hippolippo-and-minion-jim).